# Rebinding page-up via global-set-key

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to rebind my page-up and page-down keys to some functions I've written using `global-set-key`

```
(global-set-key [next] 'up-rate)
(global-set-key [previous] 'down-rate)
```

This seems to work fine for page-down, but not page-up (`previous`) - the key remains bound to "buffer page up".  Am I missing something obvious here? I have a hard time believing that this is specific to page up, but I'm not sure where to look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-h c` is your friend -- it will tell you that the name of the page up key is `prior`, not `previous`.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know about C-h c

Comment: And now that you do know about `C-h c`, you may find you start missing it anywhere else that uses keyboard commands....  It's wonderful being able to ask emacs what a key sequence will do.  (Also try `C-h k` and `C-h K` for successively more information. `C-h c`'s inverse, `C-h w`, is great, too.)

Comment: Absolutely!  In many occasions I instinctively went for one of these in some random application, only to get disappointed...